# Strange issue with Ajax file upload (jQuery, ASP.Net MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

On several pages of my web site (ASP.Net MVC, jQuery, KendoUI SPA), I have a modal window to upload a file.

```js
addAttachment: function (e) {
  $("form").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData($("#formUpload")[0]);
  var url = 'api/Attachments/UploadAttachment';
  app.postFile(url, formData, function (statusCode) {
    if (statusCode === 201) {
      // File was created -- do stuff
     
    }
  });
},
```

```html
<div id="addAttachmentWindow"
    data-role="window"
    data-height="300px"
    data-width="600px"
    data-modal="true"
    data-title="Add Attachment"
    data-visible="false">
    <div class="row">
        <form id="formUpload" class="form-horizontal">
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnRecordId" name="recordId" data-bind="value: object.id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="txtDocumentTitle">Title</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input name="documentTitle" id="txtDocumentTitle" type="text" class="k-textbox" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="fuFileInput">Document</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input id="fuFileInput" name="files" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
                <button data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-bind="click: addAttachment">Add Attachment</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the code for postFile

```
var postFile = function(uri, formData, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            callback(xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', uri);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("RequestVerificationToken", antiForgeryToken);
    xhr.send(formData);
};
```

Most of the pages, this works fine,  But on a couple of pages, it will issue the POST, without the form fields and immediately issue a GET for

```
/?recordId=1&documentTitle=documentTitleInput&files=FileNameHere.pdf
```

which goes to the Home Controller's Index function.   If I go to one of the pages with this issue, do a Shift-Reload, and try the upload it will work as expected, the form fields are intact, and the callback is called.

Issues

- Why the GET is being issued with the form fields in the query string immediately following the initial POST (even before the POST returns a response)
- Why the form fields are empty, unless I do a shift-reload on some of pages, whilethe same code works fine on other pages.

I've tried creating an empty FormData, and appending the values to it, and played everything I can find to stop the normal submit event from happening (`e.preventDefault()`, `e.stopPropogation()`, `return false` etc.);

Comment: maybe check your xhr status is 200 in postfile function ?

Comment: The Attachment controller will either return a 201 (created), or a 400 (something is wrong).  The strange thing is, the GET will occur before the POST returns anything.

Comment: Why don't you use jquery for the ajax call instead.  It works a lot better.

Comment: i posted an answer that *might* work

Comment: Adding a '/' onto the end of the URL hasn't changed anything.  I did go back to manually appending all of the form fields, and that seems to have fixed issue 2.  But issue one remains, a GET to /? with all of the form fields and their values in the query string.

Comment: updated my answer, can you try that ?

Answer (score 1):

ok so some reading on the subject and its because the prevent default only works on elements, not on a form submit event, which is what your using...

create two submit inputs...  one a button, the other a hidden input.. like so ..

```
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
<input style="display: none;" type="submit" id="realsubmit">
```

then do your jquery like so ...

```
$("#submit").on('click', function() {

  //do stuff
  $("#realsubmit").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Tried this approach, but was getting the same issue.

Comment: Hmm... this is a tough one indeed.  I can take a look at it in a few hours.  I want to know now for myself why this is happening.  haha :)